# One-to-Many relationship. Select objects from datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, groovy, jdo

I've omitted some code(package declarations, imports, other fields)
for shortness.
I have here simple One-to-Many relation.
It worked fine till this moment.

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION,
detachable="true")
class Restaurant implements Serializable {

 @PrimaryKey
 @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
 Key id

 @Persistent(mappedBy = "restaurant")
 List<RestaurantAddress> addresses = new ArrayList<RestaurantAddress>()
}
```

//-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION,
detachable="true")
class RestaurantAddress implements Serializable {

 @PrimaryKey
 @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
 Key id

 @Persistent
 Restaurant restaurant
}
```

Now i need to get(select) all the Restaurants from DB:

```
def getRestaurantsToExport(final String dst, final int count) {
   String field = restaurantExportFields[dst]
   return transactionExecute() { PersistenceManager pm ->
     Query q = pm.newQuery(Restaurant.class)
     q.filter = "$field == null"
     q.setRange(0, count)
     return q.execute()
   }
 }
```

But there are on problem - query gives me 12 restaurants(as in DB) but
every Restaurant has 0 Address but in Datastore every Restaurant has
minimum 2 addresses.

Have anyone the same problem or knows the solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone will have the same problem:

**Replace**

```
@Persistent(mappedBy = "restaurant")
 List<RestaurantAddress> addresses = new
ArrayList<RestaurantAddress>
```

**with**

```
@Persistent(mappedBy = "restaurant",defaultFetchGroup = "true")
 List<RestaurantAddress> addresses = new
ArrayList<RestaurantAddress>
```

**Another method** is that you have to "touch" addresses property for
every Restaurant in the retrieved list before closing
PersistentManager.  After PersistenManager being closed you cannot
retrieve anything from datastore and Restaurant keeps null.

Solution found with help of [google-appengine-java](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java?hl=en) users.

Comment: Do you have a link to the discussion(s) relating to this from the google group?

Answer (score 1):

are you sure the Addresses are not lazy loaded? Just a guess... is there some way to force an "eager" loading of the objects