# Lazily loaded embedded objects are not fetched completely GAE datastore

Tags: java, jdo, google-cloud-datastore

I am facing weird problem with Embedded entity inside my parent entity.

Following is the code

Below is my child entity.

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class IOU{
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.encoded-pk", value="true")
    private String iouId;

    private String groupId;
    private String fromUserId;
    private String toUserId;
    private double amount; 
}
```

It's embedded inside group.

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class Group {


    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.encoded-pk", value="true")
    private String groupId;


    private String groupName;
    private String groupType;
    private String ownerId;

    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private List<IOU> iouList;
}
```

I am doing a bit dirty work while storing them, I don't know if that's the problem.
I store them as follows.

```
group = mgr.makePersistent(group);

ArrayList<IOU> alIOU = this.generateIOUEntries(alTotalMembers, group);
group.setIouList(alIOU);
group = mgr.makePersistent(group);
```

Above is done, since I need autogenerated groupId inside my IOU.

Now the problem is when I try to fetch my group. List of iou contains only amount as property.

```
{
    "groupId" : "agdmZW0tZGV2cgsLEgVHcm91cBgEDA",
    "groupName" : "Test",
    "ownerId" : "agdmZW0tZGV2cgoLEgRVc2VyGAEM",
    "members" : [ {
      "userId" : "agdmZW0tZGV2cgoLEgRVc2VyGAIM",
    }, {
      "userId" : "agdmZW0tZGV2cgoLEgRVc2VyGAMM",
    }, {
      "userId" : "agdmZW0tZGV2cgoLEgRVc2VyGAEM",
    } ],
    "membersIdList" : [ "agdmZW0tZGV2cgoLEgRVc2VyGAIM", "agdmZW0tZGV2cgoLEgRVc2VyGAMM", "agdmZW0tZGV2cgoLEgRVc2VyGAEM" ],
    "iouList" : [ {
      "amount" : 0.0
    }, {
      "amount" : 0.0
    }, {
      "amount" : 0.0
    } ]
}
```

Weird thing is that, if I restart the server. All values are fetched properly. I am new to this JDO world, so I tried various combinations of annotation but nothing helped. I am guessing this might be related to some caching technique which is flushed to DB when I stop the server.
fromUserId and toUserId are not fetched until I restart the server.
Correct output looks like this.

```
{
    "groupId" : "agdmZW0tZGV2cgsLEgVHcm91cBgEDA",
    "groupName" : "Test",
    "ownerId" : "agdmZW0tZGV2cgoLEgRVc2VyGAEM",
    "members" : [ {
      "userId" : "agdmZW0tZGV2cgoLEgRVc2VyGAIM",
    }, {
      "userId" : "agdmZW0tZGV2cgoLEgRVc2VyGAMM",
    }, {
      "userId" : "agdmZW0tZGV2cgoLEgRVc2VyGAEM",
    } ],
    "membersIdList" : [ "agdmZW0tZGV2cgoLEgRVc2VyGAIM", "agdmZW0tZGV2cgoLEgRVc2VyGAMM", "agdmZW0tZGV2cgoLEgRVc2VyGAEM" ],
    "iouList" : [  {
  "fromUserId" : "agdmZW0tZGV2cgoLEgRVc2VyGAIM",
  "toUserId" : "agdmZW0tZGV2cgoLEgRVc2VyGAMM",
  "amount" : 0.0
}, {
  "fromUserId" : "agdmZW0tZGV2cgoLEgRVc2VyGAIM",
  "toUserId" : "agdmZW0tZGV2cgoLEgRVc2VyGAEM",
  "amount" : 0.0
}, {
  "fromUserId" : "agdmZW0tZGV2cgoLEgRVc2VyGAMM",
  "toUserId" : "agdmZW0tZGV2cgoLEgRVc2VyGAEM",
  "amount" : 0.0
} ]
}
```

Code to retrieve is as simple as following. To lazily load iouList I touch it by calling getIouList() on it.

```
Group group = mgr.getObjectById(Group.class, id);
group.getIouList()
```

Comment: obviously they aren't *embedded*, due to the absence of an @Embedded annotation, or embeddedOnly=true attribute. They are stored in a different Datastore Kind. Since no JDO API code is defined for the retrieval nobody can give an informed opinion

Comment: Can you suggest a solution then, cannot used @Embedded with collection, is their a way to do that. And why the restart behavior, that really surprises me...

Comment: A solution to what? You haven't mentioned your retrieval code, or what the log says

Comment: Already updated question with the retrieval code.

Comment: Thanks for asking so many questions, I found answer to the problem. Posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer to the problem.

Following question mentions about the same problem.
[One-to-Many relationship. Select objects from datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499140/one-to-many-relationship-select-objects-from-datastore)

For now, I touched each IOU entry in the iouList to get them loaded.

```
Group group = mgr.getObjectById(Group.class, id);
group.getIouList()

for(IOU objIOU : group.getIouList()){
    objIOU.getFromUserId();
}
```

Above code loads each property of the IOU in list.

I am guessing that only amount was getting shown previously, since it being a primitive had value of zero and other properties were null, and nulls were excluded in the serialization while creating JSON.

I might try approach of using following annotation and update about same.

```
@Persistent(mappedBy = "restaurant",defaultFetchGroup = "true")
```